# Heroku domain routing - www works, without fails

Tags: heroku, dns

I have been attempting to point my custom domain to the Heroku DNS target. I believe I have followed the steps as listed by the herokudev website. I have been able to point my domain [www.databunked.com](http://www.databunked.com) to my app. However, if I *just type* databunked.com, I am forwarded to **[www.databunked.herokuapp.com](http://www.databunked.herokuapp.com)**.

A run of `heroku domains` gives the following output:

```
Domain Name        DNS Record Type DNS Target
databunked.com     ALIAS or ANAME  left out for security
www.databunked.com CNAME           left out for security
```

I am using Godaddy.

In the **Forwarding** block in the **DNS Manager**:

[image]

In the **Records** Block:
[image]

I will be on standby to provide extra information if necessary! I appreciate any help or suggestions on how I could improve this post so you could better help me.

Answer (score 0):

Forward your root/naked domain url of Heroku hosted application using the below rule.

**Record**: ALIAS or ANAME

**Name**: empty or @ (Depending on the DNS provider)

**Target**: databunked.herokuapp.com.

Read more here - https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#configuring-dns-for-root-domains

Comment: I wanted to do that, ubt I can't because GoDaddy doesn't have ALIAS or ANAME records. Can I do a CNAME or A? Are any of these the same?